Howto use TLS 1.0 in Android
I want to connect to a local device which supports only TLS 1.0. The device's firmware cannot be updated thus I am stuck to this protocol version.
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

URL url = new URL("https://192.168.1.10/command?action=2");
HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

// Create an InputStreamReader to read the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));

// Read the response line by line and append it to the StringBuilder
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

// Close the reader and connection
reader.close();
httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
return result.toString();

But this code raises the following exception:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0x79b5fc7008: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL (external/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.cc:714 0x7ad8a4ad53:0x00000000)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)

Is there a way to connect to the server using TLS v1 in Android?
Regards,

My guess is that you would need to find an HTTP client stack that supports TLS v1, avoiding Android's SSLContext/SSLSocketFactory implementation.
